# Using NSLayoutConstraint Visual Format to set width of items

Tags: ios, iphone, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to get a hang of NSLayoutConstraints visual format and I am having a little trouble.

What I want is basically a simple UIView with two labels, one on the left, and one on the right, with heights equal to the height of the container, and the widths equal to 1/2 of the container width. The origin of the right label is aligned to the trailing of the left label.

| LEFT LABEL - RIGHT LABEL|

Anyway, here is my attempt:

```
self.leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *views     = @{ @"leftLabel"       :   self.leftLabel,
                             @"rightLabel"      :   self.rightLabel };

NSDictionary *metrics   = @{ @"width"           :   @(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2) };

NSArray *constraints;
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[leftLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[rightLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
constraints  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[leftLabel(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
constraints  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-width-[rightLabel(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];

[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Unfortunately, the width of each label remains 0 after this executes. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here's the whole class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        self.leftLabel      = [UILabel new];
        self.rightLabel     = [UILabel new];
        self.loadingView    = [[DDLoadingView alloc] init];

        self.rightLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.leftLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self addSubview:self.leftLabel];
        [self addSubview:self.rightLabel];

        [self configureLayout];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)configureLayout
{
    self.leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *views     = @{ @"leftLabel"       :   self.leftLabel,
                                 @"rightLabel"      :   self.rightLabel,
                                 @"loadingView"     :   self.loadingView  };

    NSDictionary *metrics   = @{ @"width"           :   @(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2) };

    NSArray *constraints;
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[leftLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[rightLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[leftLabel]-[rightLabel(==leftLabel)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: What does `self.frame` contain? Also its a bit unclear, but are you saying you want `LEFT LABEL` and `RIGHT LABEL` to be the same width which is half of the superview?

Comment: Yes that is what i am saying. self.frame is this: frame = (0 200; 320 40)

Comment: I think all you need is "H:|-[leftLabel]-[rightLabel(==leftLabel)]-|" if I read things correctly.

Comment: Here's my discussion of auto layout, in case you want to do some more reading :) http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the constraints to use the widths of the other views:

```
NSArray *constraints;
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[leftLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[rightLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
constraints  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[leftLabel]-[rightLabel(==leftLabel)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
```

The last constraint is saying make those two views the same width while pinning them to the left/right egdes of the superview. See the [*Equal Widths* section of the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html)

As discussed in the comments, you need to also make sure that the frame of the superview can accommodate the views themselves. `|-[` will use the default insets of `20`, using `|-2-` will give insets of `2`. If the intrinsic height of the labels is more than the views height minus these insets your view isn't going to show. So you either need to reduce the insets or increase the height of the container.

If you want more information on AutoLayout I recommend the [following series of blog posts](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) by [@jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852828/jrturton) - see the top of the article for other posts in the series. He's also got a great [category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) on `UIView` to make adding constraints easier, I use this daily!

Comment: updated my question. For some reason the labels are returning CGRectZero as the frame. I wonder if there is something in the earlier configuration that i am missing

Comment: What frame is passed in to the `initWithFrame:` method?

Comment: CGRectMake(0, 200.f, 320.f, 40.f). I can see the view itself, and the labels are in the view hierarchy, but they just have a frame of CGRectZero

Comment: The frame is too small. Either increase the height or set a inset less than the default. The `-` without a number in the constraint means the default, which I believe is 20. i.e. `@"V|[leftLabel]|"` or `@"|-2-[leftLabel]-2-|"`

Comment: Bingo!! That was the issue with my problem

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser glad you solved it. I also updated the answer with some links to a good resource on AutoLayout, hope you find them useful. I'll update my answer to point out the size/inset issue for other with the same problem in the future!